# Cucumber 'Given' step passes, but the same 'should' step fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I've been taking the SaaS course, and in Chapter 4 we're supposed to use Cucumber. I followed all the instructions and watched the screencast showing how everything worked, but still I'm stuck with this error:

```
  Scenario: Add a movie                              # features/AddMovie.feature:3

    Given I am on the RottenPotatoes home page       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44

    When I follow "Add new movie"                    # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56

    Then I should be on the Create New Movie page    # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:230

    When I fill in "Title" with "Men In Black"       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:60

    And I select "PG-13" from "Rating"               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:85

    And I press "Save Changes"                       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:52

    Then I should be on the RottenPotatoes home page # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:230

      <"/movies"> expected but was
      <"/movies/1">. (MiniTest::Assertion)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:235:in `/^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/'
      features/AddMovie.feature:10:in `Then I should be on the RottenPotatoes home page'
    And I should see "Men In Black"                  # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/AddMovie.feature:3 # Scenario: Add a movie
```

---

```
Feature: User can manually add movie

Scenario: Add a movie
    Given I am on the RottenPotatoes home page
    When I follow "Add new movie"
    Then I should be on the Create New Movie page
    When I fill in "Title" with "Men In Black"
    And I select "PG-13" from "Rating"
    And I press "Save Changes"
    Then I should be on the RottenPotatoes home page
    And I should see "Men In Black"
```

---

and the code snippet in `path.rb`

```
  def path_to(page_name)
    case page_name

    when /^the home\s?page$/
      '/'
    when /^the RottenPotatoes home page/
        movies_path
    when /^the Create New Movie page/
        new_movie_path
  end
```

---

`movies_controller.rb`

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @movies = Movie.all( :order => "title" )
end

def show
    id = params[ :id ] #    retrieve movie ID from URI route
    begin
        @movie = Movie.find( id )
    rescue
        flash[ :warning ] = "The movie was not found."
        redirect_to movies_path
    end
    #   will render app/views/movies/show.html.haml by default
end

def new
    #   default: render 'new' template
end

def create
    @movie = Movie.create( params[ :movie ] )
    flash[ :notice ] = "#{ @movie.title } was successfully created."
    redirect_to movie_path( @movie.id )
end

def edit
    id = params[ :id ]
    @movie = Movie.find_by_id( id )
end

def update
    @movie = Movie.find_by_id params[ :id ]
    @movie.update_attributes!( params[ :movie ] )
    flash[ :notice ] = "#{ @movie.title } was successfully updated."
    redirect_to movie_path( @movie )
end

def destroy
    @movie = Movie.find( params[ :id ] )
    @movie.destroy
    flash[ :notice ] = "Movie '#{ @movie.title }' deleted."
    redirect_to movies_path
end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your feature/step code? There's no way to debug this without seeing it. And also whatever code it is testing.

Comment: I've just edited my post and added the feature code.  Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: This is still not enough to debug. Can you include your movies controller code?

Comment: I added the movies controller code.  I didn't realize at first that you had asked for that too.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from what you've posted, it looks like your code and your tests don't line up. In your test you specify that after saving a new movie:

```
Then I should be on the RottenPotatoes home page
```

Which, judging from your path.rb file, looks like it translates to "should be on the movies index page". However in your code, you don't redirect to the movies index page at the end of the create action, you redirect to the show page for the movie that was just created. Which would explain why cucumber complains that it expects `<"/movies">` (the movies index page) but got `<"/movies/1">` (the page for a movie with `id = 1`).

Here's your create action:

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.create( params[ :movie ] )
  flash[ :notice ] = "#{ @movie.title } was successfully created."
  redirect_to movie_path( @movie.id )
end
```

See in the last line you have `redirect_to movie_path(@movie.id)`, which tells rails to send you to the page for the movie `@movie`. That makes sense and is often what you want (i.e. after a user creates a new record, you show them the record they created), but it's also possible that you want to redirect them to the index page where they can see the movie they added with all the other movies. The solution will be different depending on which result you want.

Assuming your test is correct, you need to change the last line in your `create` action to:

```
redirect_to movies_path
```

Hope that helps!